# How to get table column values using Div Id selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I have two questions. Table id is not available in the DOM. How do I use Div id in the following case to get to 3rd row column 2 value of '10'?

I get error on the following code which is iterating through second columns. How do I get only third row, second column?

**Jquery Code**

```
<script>
    $("'#part_li3_tt table'").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
        alert("third row second col Value: " + $(this).html());
    });
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="part_li3_tt">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>FName:</td>
                <td>Sara</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LName:</td>
                <td>Rodriguez</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Class:</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's `nth-of-type` selector, like this:

```
alert($('#part_li3_tt table tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2)').html());
```

However, I'm not sure why you need the id `part_li3_tt` in the first place, so you might be able to do this instead:

```
alert($('table tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2)').html());
```

If you're confused about how the `nth-of-type` jQuery selector works, you can read more about it here:
https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/